# A measure of similarity between two lists

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm that gives a measure of similarity between two lists, each having *n* distinct elements. The two lists are basically different arrangements of the same *n* elements.

Comment: define "similarity" in your case.

Comment: If they both have exactly the same elements then what you are talking about is a called a permutation.

Comment: As KingsIndian put it: You need to define more closely what you mean by "similar". If you can do that, the definition will often lead itself naturally to an algorithm (at least if it is not to complicated). Some examples would be: Average distance between elements, Similarity based on the number of insert/delete/replace operations, some more similarity which have been defined to check the quality of retrieval algorithms, etc. Without a defintion of similarity or a use case, this is however impossible to answer.

Comment: How close are the two lists with respect to the order of elements. (Both lists have the same elements but each list has a random arragment of those elements.)

Comment: Thanks, Hunter. Yes, to put it differently, given two nPn permutations of the same n-sized set, how similar are these two permutations? In the best case, the corresponding elements are equal, and in the worst case listA's elements are in reverse order as listB's elements.

Comment: Is it important where the lists are different? which lists are more similar to each other - one that is different from the other in the first element or in the last? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: It is not important to know what individual positions are different. The requirement is to know how similar (or different) the two lists are on the whole. But, I guess, any method that accomplishes that has to involve comparison of individual elements.

Comment: Correlation is a way to measure how associated or related two variables are.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to calculate an edit distance, i.e. the minimum number of modification steps to transform one list to the other. This would basically be the same as a Levenshtein or Damerau-Levenshtein distance, but instead of a string of characters, you're comparing a list of elements.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance